# View a list that contains the letters of your name uniquely without the space bar and a list that contains the number of occurrences and more

Tags: python

I need to make a list with my name like 'Erik Miller' and obligatory with the space,then from there a new list with unique letter like we will see only one time the 'a'
and then a third list to count the letters from the original name (the complete one)

I wrote something but at the end there is a problem

```py
def name(x):
    FirstList=[]
    for l in name :
    if l and '' not in FirstList:
    FirstList.append(l)

    SecondList=[]
    for i in FirstList:
    count=0
    for l in name:
    if l == l:
    count+=1
    return SecondList


    x="erik miller"
    prnt(x)
    prnt( FirstList)
    prnt( SecondList)
```

but in the third list something is not working
the space is counting and they are too many 1

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: the problem is not the indentation

Comment: i wrote it correctly with the good indentation just n the site it's different

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as it is currently provided in your question, can not run. There are indentation issues, the `prnt` function is indefined, lexical scopes ([PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/)) are unclear, you iterate over a function name, your conditionals don't do what you think they do (`if l and '' not in FirstList` is True even when `l` equals `" "`, `if l == l` will always be True for strings' characters, ...), there is code after the `return`, ...

There are many many mistakes. Too many mistakes.

But based on my understanding of your problem and the code you showed, here is my suggestion :

```py
from collections import Counter


def get_unique_letters_and_count(characters):
    letters = characters.replace(" ", "")
    return set(letters), Counter(letters)


name = "erik miller"
unique_letters, letters_count = get_unique_letters_and_count(name)
print(unique_letters)  # {'i', 'k', 'e', 'r', 'l', 'm'}
print(letters_count)  # Counter({'e': 2, 'r': 2, 'i': 2, 'l': 2, 'k': 1, 'm': 1})
print(letters_count["r"])  # 2
```